# Ransack and namespaced routes... Template missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

When I search anything I always have the error :

> Missing template backstage/users/search, application/search with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/RailsApps/novaxones/app/views"

I have a User model in **app/models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :created_by, :active, :blocked, :profile_attributes
  has_secure_password


  # relations
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

 [...]
```

And a controller in **controllers/backstage/users_controller.rb**

```
class Backstage::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    #@users = User.all
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

[...]

# Search
  def search
    index
    render :index
  end
end
```

And the **routes.rb** file is

```
Novaxones::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  resources :users, :controller => "frontend/users", only: [:new, :create] do
    member do
      get "activate"
    end
  end


  resources :forgotten_passwords, :controller => "frontend/forgotten_passwords", except: [:destroy, :show]
  resources :activation_requests, :controller => "frontend/activation_requests", only: [:new, :create]

  match '/forgotten_password_request', to: 'frontend/forgotten_passwords#new'
  match '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
  match '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/registration', to: 'frontend/users#new'
  match '/contact', to: 'frontend/base_pages#contact'
  match '/about', to: 'frontend/base_pages#about'
  match '/help', to: 'frontend/base_pages#help'
  match '/site-map', to: 'frontend/base_pages#sitemap', as: 'sitemap'

  namespace :backstage do
    match '', to: "dashboard#index", as: '/'
    get 'users/active' => 'users#active', :as => 'active_users'
    resources :users do
      collection do
        match 'search' => 'users#search', :via => [:get, :post], :as => :search
      end
      resources :profiles
    end
  end


  root to: 'frontend/base_pages#home'
```

As you can see I use namespaced routes to have an admin panel (called backstage)

The **index.html.erb** is

```
<div id="table-users-grid">
  <div id="grid-top-pagination" class="row">

    <div class="span4"><%= will_paginate %></div>
    <div class="span4 page-entries-info"><%= page_entries_info %></div>
    <div id="search-area" class="span4">
      <%= search_form_for @q, :url => search_backstage_users_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |sf| %>
          <div class="search-form-fields">
            <%= sf.text_field :email_cont, :placeholder => 'search users email contains' %>
          </div>
          <div class="actions"><%= sf.submit "Search" %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="management-area" class="row">
    <table id="users-grid" class="span10">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><%= link_to 'UID', :sort => "id" %></th>
        <th><%= link_to 'Last name', :sort => "profiles.last_name" %></th>
        <th><%= link_to 'First name', :sort => "profiles.first_name" %></th>
        <th><%= link_to 'Email', :sort => "email" %></th>
        <th><%= link_to 'Country', :sort => "profiles.country" %></th>
        <th>active</th>
        <th>blocked</th>
        <th>created_at</th>
        <th>created_by</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= user.id %></td>
            <td><%= user.profile.last_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.profile.first_name %></td>
            <td><%= user.email %></td>
            <td><%= user.profile.country %></td>
            <td><%= user.active %></td>
            <td><%= user.blocked %></td>
            <td><%= user.created_at.strftime("%d %B %Y") %></td>
            <td><%= user.created_by %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', backstage_user_profile_path(user, user.profile) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_backstage_user_profile_path(user, user.profile) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', backstage_user_path(user), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
    <aside id="switch-view-wrapper" class="btn-group btn-group-vertical span2" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
      <%= link_to 'All', backstage_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
      <%= link_to 'Active', backstage_active_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
      <%= link_to 'Inactive', backstage_active_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
      <%= link_to 'Blocked', backstage_active_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
      <%= link_to 'Not Blocked', backstage_active_users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </aside>
  </div>

  <div id="grid-bottom-pagination">
    <%= will_paginate %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I probably missing or misunderstood something but cannot find a way to solve that... I need Some help and explanations here.
Thanks in advance
Cheers

**EDIT AND SOLVED**

The problem was in the search action of my controller

Change from

```
 # Search
      def search
        index
        render :index
      end
    end
```

to

```
# Search
  def search
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(:distinct => true).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    render 'index'
  end
```

And all is fine now.

I had to add it to the scopes too, for those who are interested for the scope **active** in the controller the code become

```
def active
    @q = User.search(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(:distinct => true).active.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    render 'index'
  end
```

and is defined as below in the **user model**

```
# scopes
  scope :active, joins(:profile).where(:active => true)
```

Hope this can be helpful for someone else

Cheers

Comment: Add an answer and accept it; don't put the answer in the question.

Comment: I'm also not excited about your `search` method. If you have common init logic then isolate it in a separate method; it's confusing to call index then render it, and it's confusing to have an index method that isn't actually an index method. It sort-of looks like your answer (incorrectly embedded in a question) partially addresses this, but ew.

Comment: Sorry if you're not excited about the search method I just followed the gem doc https://github.com/ernie/ransack and the RailsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack.